# Accessing nested types of a template parameter T even if T is a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

Base structures:

```
struct Foo{
    typedef int inner_type;
};

template<class T>
struct Bar{
    typename T::inner_type x;
};
```

In main:

```
Bar<Foo>();  // Compiles OK
Bar<Foo*>(); // Doesn't compile: template T becomes a pointer-to-class and is not a valid class anymore.
```

How to work around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specialize the `Bar` struct for a pointer-to-`T` type:

```
//non-specialized template for generic type T
template<class T>
struct Bar{
    typename T::inner_type x;
};

//specialization for pointer-to-T types
template<class T>
struct Bar<T*>{
    typename T::inner_type x;
};
```

Comment: At that point you'd have to use a recursive method to strip off the pointers and get the original type `T`, but that wasn't what the OP was requesting, so I didn't go that far with my answer. Obviously with templates you can create something that is "complete" to cover every corner case, but typically the code is also significantly more complex.  The nice thing about the complexity is that it can be inductively proved, but still, why whip out a jack-hammer when you only need a screw-driver?   My answer is a screw-driver answer to what I feel is a screw-driver-level question by the OP.

Answer (score 7):

If you needed to do this in a situation where specializing the template would be awkward, you could also compute the type to use with some appropriate templates:

```
template<class T> struct remove_all_pointers {
    typedef T type;
};
template<class T> struct remove_all_pointers<T*> {
    typedef typename remove_all_pointers<T>::type type;
};
template<class T> struct remove_all_pointers<T* const> {
    typedef typename remove_all_pointers<T>::type type;
};
template<class T> struct remove_all_pointers<T* volatile> {
    typedef typename remove_all_pointers<T>::type type;
};
template<class T> struct remove_all_pointers<T* const volatile> {
    typedef typename remove_all_pointers<T>::type type;
};

struct Foo {
    typedef int inner_type;
};

template<class T>
struct Bar {
    typename remove_all_pointers<T>::type::inner_type x;
};
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning C++11's [std::remove_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer).

Comment: @juanchopanza: `remove_pointer` doesn't do what is required (as far as I can tell), because it does not recursively remove pointers (not that the exact requirements are particularly clear from the question). But who knows... it could be just the thing Patric is looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `typename remove_ptr<T>::type::inner_type x;` in `Bar` do the trick? Unfortunately I cannot test this right now...

Comment: Of course, this could be generalised to remove all references as well. I'm not really sure what the motivation behind this code is, so I don't know what the right behaviour is.